# TextBox без клавиатуры на WP8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

Доброго времени суток!
Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на TextBox не появлялась клавиатура (Windows Phone 8.1), но можно было бы перемещать курсор?

Comment: Сделать его read-only пробовали? Оно вам вообще зачем?

Comment: Грубо говоря мне нужны все функции TextBox-a, ноиспользовать свою клавиатуру.

Comment: Так, а зачем своя клавиатура?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Такой возможности нет. Появление клавиатуры при получении контролом фокуса зашито на уровне ОС.

Comment: А как тогда сделать свой UserControl, чтобы в нем было нечто похожее на курсор?

Comment: @ДмитрийБалашов а вот это уже другой вопрос, достойный нового поста. Только вы в нем опишите детальнее поведение, которое хотите получить.

Comment: Ссылка на этот [пост](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423946/usercontrol-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b5-textbox-wp-8-1)