# UserControl на подобие TextBox (WP 8.1)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

Доброго времени суток!
Как сделать UserControl, в котором можно отображать текст и передвигать курсор между символами? И как сделать, чтобы его можно было перемещать пальцем (как курсор в `TextBox`)? Стандартный `TextBox` не подходит, потому что автоматически открывает клавиатуру.

Comment: А чем сам `TextBox` не подходит?

Comment: @VladD см. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423911/textbox-без-клавиатуры-на-wp8-1/ (заодно поправил этот вопрос).

Comment: Ого. Ну тогда вручную, что ж. Можно посмотреть, как это сделано в стандартном стиле. Поработать придётся.

Comment: Хорошо, стиль textbox-a я нашел, но вот ничего связанного с курсором найти не могу. Где находятся "обработчики" textbox-a?

Comment: @ДмитрийБалашов: А как выглядит стиль? Положите куда-нибудь на pastebin или дайте ссылку, посмотреть.

Comment: http://pastebin.ru/L8E7iwnl#

Comment: @ДмитрийБалашов: Хм. Исходя из стиля, текст лежит в `<ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"`, но как он тем появляется — судя по всему, происходит в code-behind.

Comment: Как посмотреть code-behind?